# Sockets Authentication is failing using NegotiateStream

Tags: c#, authentication, sockets

I've got a Socket that is connected that I use to get HTTP header responses.  If I skip authentication, everything works fine (unless the page requires authentication).  But when I step into this code, it always throws an IOException on the AuthenticateAsClient line.  The message is: of "Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed."  I've tried both DefaultCredentials and DefaultNetworkCredentials.

Any ideas as to what I am missing?  What is causing the connection to close?

thanks

```
if (Authenticate)
{

    NetworkStream clientStream = new NetworkStream(webSocket, false);
    NegotiateStream authStream = new NegotiateStream(clientStream);

    NetworkCredential netcred = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;


    try
    {
        authStream.AuthenticateAsClient(netcred,
            String.Empty,
            ProtectionLevel.None,
            TokenImpersonationLevel.Identification);

        if (!authStream.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed");
            ErrorText = "Authentication using default credentials failed";
            return (HttpStatusCode)(-1);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        ErrorText = ex.Message;
        return (HttpStatusCode)(-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`NegotiateStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.negotiatestream.aspx) doesn't perform HTTP authentication:

> On Windows 95/98 systems, Windows NT LAN Manager (NTLM) is the protocol used for authentication. On other platforms the Kerberos protocol is used for authentication if both client and server support it; otherwise NTLM is used.

Have a look at the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class which provides a [Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials.aspx) and a [ResponseHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.responseheaders.aspx) property.

Comment: I'm connecting to a internal server that uses NTLM, so it should work.  I don't want to use the WebClient class as it wraps WebResponse and WebRequest. I'm trying to stay low-level with Sockets calls.

Comment: HTTP and NTLM do not work together, HTTP uses HTTP (basic or digest) authentication. If you're doing HTTP, you should first try to get it working with WebClient. If I misread your original question and you need to use NTLM, please provide more information/code.

Comment: >HTTP and NTLM do not work together

That's untrue. Most corporate Intranets use NTLM/Negotiate running over HTTP. See http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4559.txt